# django query with distinct ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='galleries', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(verbose_name=_('image'), upload_to=upload_path)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True,)
```

I want to get three last added photos. Every photo should be assigned to the different gallery.

This solution works but it is also very slow. Can I make it work faster?

```
limit = 3
photos = Photo.objects.annotate(
    max_gallery_created=Max('gallery__photos__created'),
).filter(
    gallery__site=site,
    created=F('max_gallery_created'),
).order_by(
    '-max_gallery_created',
)[:limit]
```

I will also be satisfied if I get one last added photo from each of the three last created galleries.
I tried to do this that way:

```
galleries = Gallery.objects.filter(site=site).order_by('-created').values_list('id')[:limit]
photos = Photo.objects.filter(id__in=galleries)
```

But it doesn't prevent galleries re-occurrance. I thought about using distinct() some way but I don't know how ecaxtly.

Django 1.11.

**EDIT:**

I think I should place some example for what result I expect.

```
- Gallery1 (created 10.01.2019)
    - PhotoA (created: 15.01.2019 at 12:00)
    - PhotoB (created: 15.01.2019 at 11:00)
    - PhotoC (created: 13.01.2019 at 11:00)
- Gallery2 (created 09.01.2019)
    - PhotoD (created: 13.01.2019 at 10:00)
    - PhotoE (created: 12.01.2019 at 10:00)
    - PhotoF (created: 10.01.2019 at 10:00)
- Gallery3 (created 08.01.2019)
    - PhotoG (created: 14.01.2019 at 11:00)
    - PhotoH (created: 14.01.2019 at 11:00)
    - PhotoI (created: 14.01.2019 at 11:00)
- Gallery4 (created 07.01.2019)
    - PhotoJ (created: 14.01.2019 at 12:00)
    - PhotoK (created: 12.01.2019 at 10:00)
    - PhotoL (created: 12.01.2019 at 10:00)
```

In this case

What I get now:
`PhotoA, PhotoB, PhotoJ`

What I want to get:
`PhotoA, PhotoJ, PhotoG`

I will be also satisfied if I get:
`PhotoA, PhotoD, PhotoG`

Comment: `galleries = Gallery.objects.filter(site=site).order_by('-created').distinct().values_list('id')[:limit]` try this

Comment: @SammyJ that's right but how can I get one photo from each of these galleries now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can get the latest three photos from different galleries by using one nested query. Any further filters should be added to the inner query for efficiency:

```
photos = (Photo.objects    
    .filter(id__in=Photo.objects.filter(gallery__site=site)
                                .order_by('gallery', '-created')
                                .distinct('gallery').values('id'))
    .order_by('-created')[:3]
)
```

With other backends, you can use a prefetch subquery as proposed by Bernhard, although his solution will get you all galleries sorted by gallery date, with the latest three photos in each.

With an additional filter that sorts and limits galleries by photo date rather than gallery date, you can get the same result as above: the latest 3 photos, with the restriction of only one photo per gallery:

```
prefetch = Prefetch('photos', queryset=Photo.objects.filter(id__in=
    Subquery(Photo.objects.filter(
        gallery_id=OuterRef('gallery_id')
    ).order_by('-created').values_list('id', flat=True)[:1])))


galleries = (Gallery.objects
    .filter(id__in=Gallery.objects
                    .order_by('-photos__created')
                    .distinct()[:3]
            )
    .order_by('-created')
    .prefetch_related(prefetch)
)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, your query gives me just three last created `Photo` objects with no "just one per gallery" restriction. The `Photo.objects.order_by('-created', 'gallery').distinct('created', 'gallery')[:3].values_list('gallery_id', flat=True)` gives me `<QuerySet [660, 660, 660]>` , which means that `distinct()` doesn't really work.

Comment: Now it's almost what I need! The only problem is that gallery site filter is not included in your PostgreSQL solution.

Comment: You can just prepend any filter you need, see above.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I made it work with your help yesterday:) I did it with the second part (Prefetch and Subquery one) of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.11 you should be able to do this with a combination of [`Subquery` Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Prefetch

subquery = Subquery(
    Photo.objects.filter(
        gallery_id=OuterRef('gallery_id')
    ).order_by('-created').values_list('id', flat=True)[:3])

galleries = Gallery.objects.order_by('-created').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('photos',
        queryset=Photo.objects.filter(id__in=subquery).order_by('-created')))

for gallery in galleries:
    for photo in gallery.photos.all(): # should now be the latest 3
        print(photo)
```

If you want to fetch the latest photos to a different attribute than `photos` you can use the `to_attr` argument of the [`Prefetch` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch).

Comment: I am sorry but that's not what I want to achieve. Maybe I am not really good at giving explanations so I just put an example in my question. Take a look, please.

Comment: Yes sorry, i misunderstood it, I thought you meant you want the last 3 photos per gallery.